# Xamarin IOS app fails

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

New to using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015. I have set up what I think is a very simple IOS app where it counts the number of button clicks.. I am using a MacInCloud machine as my build host. I am using an IPhone simulator.

When I build and deploy, the application sort of flashes for a moment and then goes away. It does this repeatedly. In the output window I get the following error

> *Launching 'NewApp.iOS' on 'iPhone 5 iOS 9.0'...
>   The app has been terminated.
>   Launch failed. The app 'NewApp.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone 5 iOS 9.0'. Error: An error occurred while executing MTouch. Please check the logs for more details.
>   The app has been terminated.*

If anybody can offer me some direction with this it would be greatly appreciated.

--Jason

Comment: This seems like a temporary issue. Probably just pull the cable out of the phone and connect it again.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I had this specific issue. Try cleaning your project. Possibly go as far as deleting the bin/debug folder contents in your IOS project. Make sure your architecture is set to 86_64 under the build / advance tab. Make sure your MAC build client is up to date, Make sure you are building for debug. close VS and reopen. Also do a cold restart on your mac and windows machines. Don't "Reopen windows" either.